# How to add passive values to radio buttons

Tags: javascript, html

I want while the turtle radio button is selected for there to be a passive increase in strength like this:

[image]

Also on level up, I want it to add +1 to that value so when the turtle is level 2 the passive is +2 strength.

I'm mostly wondering how you do passive effects in HTML. Do radio buttons have the ability to passively modify variables when selected? My idea is similar to changing gear in an RPG. I would also like `Cexp` to go up 1 every second when the radio button is selected.

Here is my current code:

```
var Turtle = 1;
var Turtlelv = 1;
var TurtleCexp = 0;
var TurtleMexp = 100;
var NextMaxTurtleExp = TurtleMexp;
var Turtlestrength = 1 + Strength

function turtlepassive() {
    if (TurtleCexp < NextMaxTurtleExp) {
        TurtleCexp = TurtleCexp + 1;
        document.getElementById("TurtleCexp").innerHTML = TurtleCexp;
    } else {
        Turtlelv = Turtlelv + 1;
        TurtleCexp = 0;
        Turtle = Turtle + 1;
        Turtlestrength = Turtlestrength + 1;
        NextMaxTurtleExp = NextMaxTurtleExp * 1.5;
        document.getElementById("Strength").innerHTML = Strength;
        document.getElementById('TurtleMexp').innerHTML = 
NextMaxTurtleExp;
        document.getElementById('Turtlelv').innerHTML = Turtlelv;
        document.getElementById('TurtleCexp').innerHTML = TurtleCexp;
        document.getElementById('Turtle').innerHTML = Turtle;
     }
}
```

Html code:

```
<div id="turtle" class="control">
    <label class="radio">
        <input type="radio" name="Pets">
    </label>
    <img src="turtle.png" alt="turtle" height="100" width="100">Lv <span id="Magiclv">1</span> <span id="MagicCexp">0</span> / <span id="MagicMexp">100</span>
</div>
```

I expect while the turtle radio button is selected for `exp` to go up by 1 every second and to have a passive buff to strength by 1 at level 1 and 2 at level 2 and so on. But the actual result I can't get this to work properly.

Comment: Try creating a working example in the code snippet creator. It will go a long way to helping us help you

Comment: In the context of radio buttons...what do you mean by *"passive"*? I googled and in the results nothing really stood out from the usual information concerning radio buttons, JavaScript, or HTML...

Comment: @zer00ne asker wants to have it so the buttons automatically increase/decrease variables when selected, it's not possible to my knowledge. My answer explains how this could be done, though.

Comment: In rpgs when you equip a weapon that weapon increases a value ( like strength or intelligence) by a certain amount. When you unequip that weapon those stats go away but they are stored on that weapons attributes. Thats what im trying to accomplish. while first button is selected do function etc. but if button not selected dont do function

Comment: @tmanrocks994 Ok see my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56388275/2813224)

Answer (score 1):

Radio buttons can't passively change a variable, but this can be done programmatically.

This is basic code (that you should remake for your program) demonstrating how you could have strength affected by whether or not the turtle is selected and the turtle's level. When the turtle is selected, it adds the amount to the variable, and when the turtle is deselected it removes the amount.

```html
<div id="turtle" class="control">
  <label class="radio">
    <input type="radio" name="Pets" id="turtle-radio">
```

```
document.getElementById("turtle-radio").addEventListener("change", () => {
  if (document.getElementById("turtle-radio").checked) {
    //increase strength by level
  } else {
    //decrease strength by level
  }
}
```

As for updating the turtle's level over time, this can also be done. Let's assume that the turtle always needs 100xp to level up. Every second that the radio is checked, it will add 1xp to the turtle and set a `timeout` for another check. When the xp reaches 100, have the turtle level up. When the radio button isn't check, the `timeout` shouldn't refresh.

```
function turtleXpUp() {
  if (document.getElementById("turtle-radio").checked) {
    setTimeout(turtleXpUp, 1000)
    //turtle xp +1
  }
  if (/* xp == 100*/) {
    if (document.getElementById("turtle-radio").checked) {
      //increase strength by 1
      //increase level by 1
    }
  }
}
document.getElementById("turtle-radio").addEventListener("change", turtleXpUp)
```

Comment: what about making it like this  var Strength = 1       var Turtlestrength = 1               
 var Turtleandstrength = Strength + Turtlestrength       .  Then when the button is not selected remove Turtlestrength from Turtleandstrength mabey. ill try what you suggested. ill tell you if it works.

Comment: where do i add the 2nd part of code? with the "f (document.getElementById("turtle-radio").checked) {
    //increase strength by level" . Do i put that in javascript under the function or with the function

Comment: @tmanrocks994 for your first comment, that's what I was telling you to do if I understand correctly.

Comment: also how do i call the function or attached it to the radio button

Comment: @tmanrocks994 I showed you how to attach it to the radio button, that's what `.addEventListener` does, using the radio button's ID. And the answer has been updated for your second comment.

Comment: o ok. i'm just having a hard time getting it to work  http://prntscr.com/nv63dh  this is what i have so far is not working  . http://prntscr.com/nv64kf  . adds 1 to strength but isn't increasing turtlCexp its increasing the lv

Comment: the 2 under the radio button is strengths default value. it's actually not changing when i press the button should go up by turtle strength. where do I add  http://prntscr.com/nv66re

Comment: http://prntscr.com/nv6a3w   I have this now but now strength isn't changing at all and when i change radio buttons it auto levels the turtle and sets exp to 0 . http://prntscr.com/nv6acz

Comment: http://prntscr.com/nv6ib3   Everything is working now cept when I click a different button the strength doesn't update correctly. on first click base strength goes from 2 to 3 then when i click off it should go down to 2 but it stays on 3 then when I click it again it goes up to 4 instead of back to 3

Comment: @tmanrocks994 (1) `Turtle`, `Turtlelv`, and `Turtlestrength` are all exactly the same variable so I suggest you consolidate them. (2) It seems that `Strength` does update properly, the issue is that its display only changes when the turtle update loop (`turtleXpUp()`) runs. However, because the turtle is deselected, the display of strength doesn't update. To fix this issue, move the changing of the display of `Strength` to be in `turtleandstrength()`.

Comment: what do you mean by that fix? I have http://prntscr.com/nv7f4z this but its still not updateing correctly. do i need to add more document.getelementbyids somewhere

Comment: @tmanrocks994 can I see where the entire script? I can't find where `TurtleMexp` is defined.

Comment: if you can still help me id appreciate it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56411499/making-a-simple-true-false-flag-for-each-radio-button            I made a new post. im at a point where my wolf button works to switch to lizard but if u switch from turtle to lizard it takes away 1 strength. if we can start a chat or i can get some help to finish this part of my game I would love it

Comment: I solved it     i added a StoredStrength= Strength to my variables then made else Strength= StoredStrength