# Making a simple true / false flag for each radio button

Tags: javascript, html

So   I want to  make a function to see which radio button is active, then process the effects of removing that effect  with a true/false flag for each radio button turtle, wolf, lizard, etc . 
So like

```
var wolfActive = true;
var lizardActive = false;
var turtleActive = false;
```

Then when you set one of those active you pass to a function and look at all the others to see if it's true.  If it's true, subtract it's values.
And then set the others to false.

I mostly want this done so when you switch radio buttons the stats/ functions tied to those radio buttons don't carry over. When switching from turtle to lizard I lose 1 strength and that shouldn't happen with this method. Im new to doing JavaScript so this kind of concept im not sure how to set up to make it work.  I will show you in my code what i mean

I had someone  try to explain it to me but i couldn't format it correctly.

He said "When the radiobutton changes make the eventlistener call a function which determines which of those is active then create a function to figure out what is active and make a remove for each one
Part of the remove is to set it false
Then after that's finished set the new one true"

This is my JavaScript code:

```js
 var wolfRadio = document.getElementById("wolf-radio");
 var lizardRadio = document.getElementById("lizard-radio");
 var wolfInterval;

 var Wolf = 1;
 var Wolflv = 1;
 var WolfCexp = 0;
 var WolfMexp = 100;
 var NextMaxWolfExp = WolfMexp;
 var Wolfstrength = 1;
 var Strength = 2;

 // This is an event dispatcher function. Based on the radio
 // button that was clicked, run different functions.
 function radioChanged(event) {
  if (event.target === wolfRadio) {
    wolfandstrength(true);
    wolfXpUp(true);
    // Run other functions...
  } else if (event.target === lizardRadio) {
    wolfandstrength(false);
    wolfXpUp(false);
   // Run other functions...
  }
}

function wolfandstrength(wolfChecked) {
  if (wolfChecked) {
    Strength = Strength + Wolfstrength
document.getElementById("Strength").innerHTML = Strength;
  } else {
    Strength = Strength - Wolfstrength;
    document.getElementById("Strength").innerHTML = Strength;
  }
}

function wolfXpUp(wolfChecked) {
  clearInterval(wolfInterval);

  if (wolfChecked && WolfCexp < WolfMexp) {
   wolfInterval = setInterval(function () { wolfXpUp(wolfChecked); }, 
  200);
    WolfCexp = WolfCexp + 1;
    document.getElementById("WolfCexp").innerHTML = WolfCexp;
  } 

  if (WolfCexp >= WolfMexp) {
    Wolflv = Wolflv + 1;
    WolfCexp = 0;
    Wolf = Wolf + 1;
      Wolfstrength = Wolfstrength + 1;
      Strength = Strength + 1;
       NextMaxWolfExp = NextMaxWolfExp * 1.5;
    }

    document.getElementById("Strength").innerHTML = Strength;
    document.getElementById('WolfMexp').innerHTML = NextMaxWolfExp;
   document.getElementById('Wolflv').innerHTML = Wolflv;
    document.getElementById('WolfCexp').innerHTML = WolfCexp;
    //document.getElementById('Turtle').innerHTML = Turtle; 
  }

  //document.getElementById("turtle-radio").addEventListener("change", 
  turtleXpUp);
  //document.getElementById("turtle-radio").addEventListener("change", 
  turtleandstrength);
  wolfRadio.addEventListener("change", radioChanged);
  lizardRadio.addEventListener("change", radioChanged);
  document.getElementById("Strength").innerHTML = Strength;
```

```html
 <div id="turtle" class="control">
   <label class="radio">
     <input type="radio" name="Pets" id="turtle-radio">
   </label><img src="turtle.png" alt="turtle" height="100" width="100"> Lv 
   <span id="Turtlelv">1</span> <span id="TurtleCexp">0</span> / <span 
  id="TurtleMexp">100</span>
       <br />
       <br />

       <div id="lizard" class="control">
         <label class="radio">
            <input type="radio" name="Pets" id="lizard-radio">
        </label><img src="lizard.png" alt="lizard" height="42" width="42"> 
    &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;Lv <span 
    id="Lizardlv">1</span> <span id="LizardCexp">0</span> / <span 
    id="LizardMexp">100</span>
       <br />
        <div id="wolf" class="control">
          <label class="radio">
            <input type="radio" name="Pets" id="wolf-radio">
           </label><img src="wolf.png" alt="wolf" height="60" width="60"> 
    &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; Lv <span id="Wolflv">1</span> <span 
    id="WolfCexp">0</span> / <span id="WolfMexp">100</span></div>
       <br />
      <span id="Strength">0</span>
```

You can see from the snippet switching from wolf to lizard radio button works fine because you start with 2 strength. But when you switch from turtle to lizard I don't want you to lose 1 strength. Each radio buttons buffs should only be on while the radio button is selected. (hence why i want a good true/false flag) . My actual output the radio buttons functions / stats aren't tied to directly to them being selected. I'm hoping makinging the other radio buttons false while one is true will fix this.

Comment: I might of set up the snippet thing wrong i tried. if someone can edit it to make it work id appreciate it. The code works in my editor.

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. Please consider explaining what the correct output is for each case. You've gone into "Wolf" and "Lizard" etc, but quite frankly I have no idea what any of that means. It would be easier if you just showed some examples or drastically simplified your explanation to be more generic.

Comment: ok. I only have one function set up so far but I want while the Wolf radio button is selected for Strength to be = to Strength = Strength +WolfStrength. that bonus gets increases as you level up that pet. If that radio button is not selected that bonus Strength should go away and you should go back to what you had before the radio button was selected. lizard i was going to do basically the same thing but have it give you magic. so when that radio tab is not active that bonus to magic should go away. turtle I was going to do a hp/manaregen buff.

Comment: but my current problem is i dont have a good way to keep stats/ variables tied to that radio button because if you switch from turtle to lizard at the moment your strength goes down by 1.  so a true/false flag to check if a radio button is selected then if it isnt its functions are false or how ever true/false flags are done. the person helping me said to like minus them so the before false.

Comment: like if Wolfactive    then plus 5 to strength . If lizard active +5 to magic but if lizard is active it shouldnt have the plus 5 to strength also because you switch the that button. the stat buffs should only be in effect while the radio button is selected

Comment: I will try to get the snippet to work. That would help explain it. http://prntscr.com/nwhx1o this is when the program runs no button selected. the 2 represents strength. http://prntscr.com/nwhx68  this is when the wolf radio button is selected it buffs strength by 1 then when it levels up buffs it by 2 and so on  http://prntscr.com/nwhxlw  when i select lizard the strength goes back down to what it was before the radio button was selected (2) and then the 2nd number down is magic that starts to increase. http://prntscr.com/nwhytg i dont have anything for turtle yet

Comment: but the 2nd number down should be 1 not 2 because you change from lizard to turtle so lizards bonuses should go away. http://prntscr.com/nwhz31  now the biggest issue is switching from turtle to lizard that minuses the strength stat by 1 even though strength shouldnt be touched. it should stay the value it was before the wolf radio button is selected. i cant do strength =  etc because i have it ever changing on other parts of this game.

Comment: i think this posts snippet should work .might need more buttons . i will take a look at your answer ty so much

Answer (score 1):

So, I may have rewritten this a bit *too* much, but personally I'd go a route like the following.

To define which pet gets which buff, and how much that buff is, use **data attributes**. For example, if `wolf` should buff `strength` by `1`, then it would have `data-buff-type="strength"` and `data-buff-amount="1"` in the HTML.

Then, you can store the base stats separately, and have a function that checks/applies the pet buff. I've added comments beside each line to explain.

```js
var baseStats = {
  strength: 1,
  mana: 1,
  regen: 1
};

function getStats() {
  var selectedPet = document.querySelector('input[name="Pets"]:checked');  //Find the selected pet
  if (!selectedPet) return baseStats;                                      //No pet selected, just return base stats
  
  var buffType = selectedPet.dataset.buffType;                             //Get selected pet's data-buff-type
  var buffAmount = parseInt( selectedPet.dataset.buffAmount );             //Get selected pet's data-buff-amount
  
  var stats = {...baseStats};                                              //Copy our base stats
  stats[buffType] += buffAmount;                                           //Find the buff-type, add the buff-amount to it
  
  return stats;                                                            //Return the buffed stats
}

function updateStats() {
  var stats = getStats();                                                      //Get buffed stats
  document.querySelectorAll(".stat").forEach(e => e.innerHTML = stats[e.id]);  //Set spans where ID matches stat type
}

//Add listener to all radio buttons
document.querySelectorAll('input[name="Pets"]').forEach(e => e.addEventListener("change", updateStats));

//Set the stats on page-load
updateStats();
```

```css
div { margin: 5px 0; }
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="radio" name="Pets" id="wolf-radio" data-buff-type="strength" data-buff-amount="1">
  <label for="wolf-radio">Wolf</label>
</div>

<div>
  <input type="radio" name="Pets" id="lizard-radio" data-buff-type="mana" data-buff-amount="1">
  <label for="wolf-radio">Lizard</label>
</div>

<div>
  <input type="radio" name="Pets" id="turtle-radio" data-buff-type="regen" data-buff-amount="1">
  <label for="wolf-radio">Turtle</label>
</div>

<div>
  Strength: <span class="stat" id="strength"></span>
</div>

<div>
  Mana: <span class="stat" id="mana"></span>
</div>

<div>
  Regen: <span class="stat" id="regen"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: omg thank you that works. let me test it will all my messy code haha. ive been looking for like 3 days for a good solution. your a lifesaver. I dont know if you like games but now i can sue this also to make equipment /swords. should I undo my change to the top code for others? or is this newer on cleaner

Comment: Now I just need a way to use cookies to save between tabs http://prntscr.com/nwi2ia  when i switch tabs data on one tab compleatly gets erased because I have it set in html css each tab is a diffrent javasciprt / html page. then i should be able to finish this.

Comment: For storing data, check out [local storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).

Comment: wouldnt that make the game data storage perm? i want it to reset everytime i close the game. at the moment it resets on tab change and close.

Comment: if it was perm i wouldnt be able to test stuff i think

Comment: I just relized. the base stats cant be = to something. I guess i could change this to be where Strength magic and regen is pulled from but Strength could be 2, 3 4 any number. this tab on my game is unlocked after resetting the game 3 times and Strength is gained from many sources. from a skill tree , and another leveling system . is there a way to make the variables = to the ever changing stats. ? thats why i had in my  wolfandstrength function else Strength = Strength - Wolfstrength. so strength would go back to what it was before the radio button was checked.

Comment: It almost works but how do i change those to just be equal to strength, magic , regen not a base stat. or does that not matter.